# Add new section in Craft 3 Migrations

Tags: craft3, migration

I have been trying to get my head wrapped around Migrations in Craft 3 and find myself struggling with added a new section.

I have managed to add a new volume, but not a section. Here’s where I have got to so far…

```
<?php

namespace craft\contentmigrations;

use Craft;
use craft\db\Migration;

/**
 * m180428_195138_test migration.
 */
class m180428_195138_test extends Migration
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function safeUp()
    {

      if (is_null(Craft::$app->volumes->getVolumeByHandle("newvolume"))) {
        $volume = new \craft\volumes\Local([
          "name" => "New volume",
          "handle" => "newvolume",
          "hasUrls" => true,
          "url" => "@web/images/newvolume",
          "path" => "@webroot/images/newvolume"
        ]);

        Craft::$app->volumes->saveVolume($volume);
      }


      if (is_null(Craft::$app->sections->getSectionByHandle("awesomeNews"))) {
        $section = new \craft\models\Section([
          'name' => 'Awesome News',
          'handle' => 'awesomeNews',
          'type' => 'Channel',
          'siteSettings' => [
              new \craft\models\Section_SiteSettings([
                  'siteId' => Craft::$app->sites->getPrimarySite()->id,
                  'enabledByDefault' => true,
                  'hasUrls' => true,
                  'uriFormat' => 'foo/{slug}',
                  'template' => 'foo/_entry',
              ]),
          ]
        ], true);

        Craft::$app->sections->saveSection($section);

      }


    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function safeDown()
    {

      $newvolume = Craft::$app->volumes->getVolumeByHandle("newvolume");
      if (!is_null($newvolume)) {
        Craft::$app->volumes->deleteVolumeById($newvolume->id);
      }

      $awesomeNews = Craft::$app->sections->getSectionByHandle("awesomeNews");
      if (!is_null($awesomeNews)) {
        Craft::$app->volumes->deleteSectionById($awesomeNews->id);
      }

    }
}
```

The migration states it has been successful, however, I only see the new volume, not the section. I have tried to execute this with only the block relating to the section.

Does anyone know if it is possible to create a new section with Migrations? If it is, any idea what may be wrong with the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution for this by far is to just run the `$model->getErrors()` function in order to see what's wrong.. Then you'll see the following:

> "Type is invalid."

Take a look at your `Section` model

```
const TYPE_CHANNEL = 'channel';
```

change

```
'type' => 'Channel',
```

to

```
'type' => 'channel',
```

or even better

```
'type' => Section::TYPE_CHANNEL,
```

Also: every `save` function returns a variable of type `boolean` if it was successful or not. You should **always** check for those values.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The incorrect case for channel was an artefact of trying a hundred different ways to get this to work, however, it was this and another error causing the issue. The tip about `$model->getErrors()` is really useful.

Using

`'type' => Section::TYPE_CHANNEL,` 

work a treat.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As documentation for Migrations is pretty slim, here is the working code:

```
<?php

namespace craft\contentmigrations;

use Craft;
use craft\db\Migration;

/**
 * m180428_195138_test migration.
 */
class m180428_195138_test extends Migration
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function safeUp()
    {


      if (is_null(Craft::$app->volumes->getVolumeByHandle("newvolume"))) {
        $volume = new \craft\volumes\Local([
          "name" => "New volume",
          "handle" => "newvolume",
          "hasUrls" => true,
          "url" => "@web/images/newvolume",
          "path" => "@webroot/images/newvolume"
        ]);

        $success = Craft::$app->volumes->saveVolume($volume);

      }

      if (is_null(Craft::$app->sections->getSectionByHandle("awesomeNews"))) {
        $section = new \craft\models\Section([
          "name" => "Awesome News",
          "handle" => "awesomeNews",
          "type" => \craft\models\Section::TYPE_CHANNEL,
          "siteSettings" => [
              new \craft\models\Section_SiteSettings([
                  "siteId" => Craft::$app->sites->getPrimarySite()->id,
                  "enabledByDefault" => true,
                  "hasUrls" => true,
                  "uriFormat" => "foo/{slug}",
                  "template" => "foo/_entry",
              ]),
          ]
        ]);

        $success = Craft::$app->sections->saveSection($section);

        $errors = $section->getErrors();
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
          echo $error[0];
        }

      }

      return $success;

    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function safeDown()
    {

      $newvolume = Craft::$app->volumes->getVolumeByHandle("newvolume");
      if (!is_null($newvolume)) {
        $success = Craft::$app->volumes->deleteVolumeById($newvolume->id);
      }

      $awesomeNews = Craft::$app->sections->getSectionByHandle("awesomeNews");
      if (!is_null($awesomeNews)) {
        $success = Craft::$app->sections->deleteSectionById($awesomeNews->id);
      }

      return $success;

    }


}
```

This includes the error checking when creating the new section and the `save` functions are assigned to a variable which are returned at the end.

Comment: Just a side note: migrations are one of the few things that are really well documented https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-migrations since Craft doesn't handle them